# Getting correct index from input array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you get the proper index of a selected input from a set of input elements with irregularly numbered indexes using JQuery?  JQuery's "index" function always returns a value starting from 0 instead of the indexes I used.  My code is below:

JQuery:

```
$("input[name^=myboxes]").click(function() {
        var element_id = $("input[name^=myboxes]").index(this);
        alert(element_id); //will alert 0, 1, or 2 instead of 3, 8, or 10
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[3]" name="myboxes[3]" value="CHECKED"  >
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[8]" name="myboxes[8]" value="CHECKED"  >
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[10]" name="myboxes[10]" value="CHECKED" CHECKED >
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of your ID does not have an "index" property.  It's just a string.

One suggestion: parse the id string to get your value:

```
$("input[name^=myboxes]").click(function() {
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //the initial starting point of the substring is based on "myboxes["
    var ix = element_id.substring(8,element_id.length - 1)
    alert(ix);
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

The following is what has always worked for me.

JQuery:

```
$("input[name^=myboxes]").click(function() {
        var element_id = $(this).attr("meta:index");
        alert(element_id);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[3]" name="myboxes[3]" meta:index="3" value="CHECKED"  >
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[8]" name="myboxes[8]" meta:index="8" value="CHECKED"  >
<input type="checkbox" id="myboxes[10]" name="myboxes[10]" meta:index="10" value="CHECKED" CHECKED >
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Similar concept to use is data- attributes.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer has a few issues with syntax  it should be:

```
$("input[name^=myboxes]").click(function() {
    var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
    //the initial starting point of the substring is based on "myboxes["
    var ix = element_id.substring(8,element_id.length - 1);
    alert(ix);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be even shorter if you do it like this:

```
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
       // remove everything that is not a number
       id = id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
       alert(id);
```